# Is there anyway JSON(node: ) can be called with [String: Any] type in Vapor

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

I have a method, which will return a `[String: Any]` dictionary as below,

```
  func getDetailDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
    // demo code
    let followers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    return [
      "name": "sample name",
      "followers": followers
    ]
  }
```

I need to convert this object to `JSON`, so that I can send it back to the client as a `ResponseRepresentable` object.

I used the following to prepare the JSON object:

```
let jsonData = try JSON(node: getDetailDictionary())
```

But this giving error, telling this doesn't match any available overloads. I don't think `[String:Any]` type is not handled in `JSON(node: )` method implementation. Is there any way we can get this issue resolved in Vapor?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk This question is purely related to the server side swift framework - Vapor. Please have a look at the description once more, I'd made some minor updates.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this code working by assigning the type of all the values to `Node`. This might not be what you want if you want to interact with the data in the dictionary before returning it, but I think it will work.

```
func getDetailDictionary() -> Node {
    // demo code
    let followers: Node = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    let dict: Node = [
        "name": "sample name",
        "followers": followers
    ]
    return dict
}

drop.get("test") { req in
    return JSON(getDetailDictionary())
}
```